# MySQL query select rows from A and combine multiple rows from B

Tags: php, mysql

After looking into this, apparently it's a complex thing to do? It doesn't look like it's a pivot query, or should it be?? Anyway, two tables like this:

articles:

```
id    col2    col3
 1    ....    ....
 2    ....    ....
 3    ....    ....
```

articleImages:

```
id    imgFile    artRef
 1    img1.jpg   1
 2    img2.jpg   1
 3    img3.jpg   2
 4    .......    3
 5    .......    3
 6    .......    3
```

I want to select everything form "articles" and combine the "articleImages" into the row so it will look something like this:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "col2":"...",
    "col3":"...",
    "imgFiles":{
        "img1.jpg",
        "img2.jpg"
    }
  },{
    "id":"2",
    "col2":"...",
    "col3":"...",
    "imgFiles":{
        "img3.jpg"
    }
  },{
    "id":"3",
    ...etc.
}]
```

I tried:

```
"SELECT art.*, ai.imgFile FROM articles art LEFT JOIN articleImages ai ON art.id = ai.artRef ORDER BY art.id desc LIMIT $lim, $limit"
```

And that's wrong...I got separate rows for each image.  It's not a `LEFT JOIN`...what's the syntax for this?  Or is there a more optimal way of organizing the table?  I didn't want to make an "articleImages" column and concatenate inside "articles"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your goal correctly you can group your query and use `GROUP_CONCAT` function to get all coma separated img names in one field:

```
SELECT art.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(ai.imgFile) imgFiles
FROM articles art 
LEFT JOIN articleImages ai 
ON art.id = ai.artRef 
GROUP BY art.id
ORDER BY art.id desc 
LIMIT $lim, $limit
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the right output.  The image files get concatenated with a comma...is there a way to make it into an array, like I had in my question?

Comment: in your question you have something like json array, I have no idea how you generate it, so show your code where you generate that array and we can figure out how to fix it

Comment: You're right, it was actually the javascript console log from an AJAX response.  I read about `GROUP_CONCAT` and saw that you can specify a separator because I think a comma is too unreliable.  Thanks for the answer!  I couldn't formulate the right question to ask google :)

Comment: I would recommend not play with query, but fix your array on php side.

Comment: You mean to keep the query how you said but change the "imgFiles" concat?

Comment: I mean show the php code and I will help you to fix it you need there something like `$row['imgFiles'] = explode($row['imgFiles']);`

Comment: I understand that part...it was the query which I was struggling with.  No problems anymore, thanks again!